# what to add a repo to my current $PATH on mac?

Tags: git, unix, terminal

Let's say that I find a repo at Github I want to execute the program from  my terminal.
And so I need to add this repo to my current $PATH right? 
Right now I do this:

```
touch ~/.bash_profile; open ~/.bash_profile
```

and I find:

```
export PATH="/usr/local/bin:$PATH"

[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && source "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" # Load RVM into a shell session *as a function*
```

So in the repo of my choice says that: **"After cloning this repository, put it in your $PATH and ensure it is executable."**

How Do I do this?
Shall I add a new url to /.bash_profile like:

export PATH="/usr/local/bin/THIS_NEW_REPO:$PATH"
Thank you!
Y/

Comment: Path != URL. And `PATH` is colon-separated, so put a `:` in there.

Comment: @larsmans Hi there! wanna be more specific? u mean like this: Path != URL:PATH

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you should do that the way you wrote. Also make sure that the repo is executable. In case you don't already know, you can do that by typing:

```
sudo chmod +x -R /usr/local/bin/THIS_NEW_REPO
```